# weighted average with sumproduct and offset

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to do the following: Calculate a weighted average based on the scenario shown in the sample screenshot. The question I would like to anser is: What is the total amount of sales generated by employee A and employee B, respectively, in a given period (here: in 2021).

Screenshot:
[image]

My Idea was to use a sumproduct formula which selects first all items with reference to employee A and, secondly, all sales of a given product. I use the `ISNUMBER(FIND())` construct as wildcard (e.g. with *) does not work with `SUMPRODUCT()` as far as I know. However, this formula does not work properly. Any suggestions?

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[item]=$J46);Table1[2021];--(ISNUMBER(FIND("Sale";TabLe1[item])));Table1[2021])`

Comment: It's quite hard to get what you want from the structure as presented. I think the table is fed by other data, correct? I think it's better to search your answer in that data.

Comment: Table content is actually hard coded.

Comment: That is really not how one should put data together. If it's hard-coded, what are the chances you can actually transform this into a proper set of data?

Comment: The source data is hard coded and I want to consolidated this input with formula. I don't see why this would be bad as you have to start with some input data independently if this input is hard coded or pulled from any given source.

Comment: From a database point-of-view this layout is *bad*, no doubt about that. Employees directly underneath a header called items? Percentages and numbers mixed in the same column? No way a proper data-engineer made this database. Now, trying to make something out of it is, offcourse, a good intention!

Answer (score 2):

Office 365 required:
`=SUMPRODUCT(FILTER(Table1[2021],LEFT(Table1[item],4)="sale"),FILTER(Table1[2021],Table1[item]=$J46))`

[image]

For older Excel version you could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[2021])*--(Table1[item]=J49),. 
            (OFFSET(Table1[2021],1-MATCH(J49,Table1[item],0),,))*
            --(LEFT(OFFSET(Table1[item],1-MATCH(J49,Table1[item],0),,),4)="sale"))
```

This is provided that each employee is offset the same way for each sale product.

Comment: If you don't have Office 365, let me know.

Comment: Currently,, i am working with Excel 2013. The filter function is not yet available. Any workaround adapted to my version?

Comment: I tried `=SUMPRODUCT((--(Table1[item]=$J42)*Table1[2021]),(LEFT(Table1[item],4)="Sale")*Table1[2021])`. This formula gives back a value of 0 as the two arrays are offset. Is there a way to build on this formula?

Comment: See my edit for a solution for older Excel.